# Correctly call a function in a nested class from an outer class C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, assignment-operator

For part of an assignment, I'm supposed to create an assignment operator for a class called `HashGraph` that my professor created.

This is what the function prototype looks like:

```
HashGraph<T>& operator = (const HashGraph<T>& rhs);
```

Within this `HashGraph<T>` class, I have a nested private class called `LocalInfo` which stores four sets (defined by my professor) and a reference to a `HashGraph`. Here is the nested private class:

```
  private:
    //All methods and operators relating to LocalInfo are defined below, followed by
    //  friend functions for insertion onto output streams of HashGrah and LocalInfo
    class LocalInfo {
      public:
        LocalInfo()                : from_graph(nullptr), out_nodes(hash_str), in_nodes(hash_str), out_edges(hash_pair_str), in_edges(hash_pair_str) {}
        LocalInfo(HashGraph<T>* g) : from_graph(g),       out_nodes(hash_str), in_nodes(hash_str), out_edges(hash_pair_str), in_edges(hash_pair_str) {}
        void connect(HashGraph<T>* g) {from_graph = g;}

        bool operator == (const LocalInfo& rhs) const {
          return this->in_nodes == rhs.in_nodes && this->out_nodes == rhs.out_nodes &&
                 this->in_edges == rhs.in_edges && this->out_edges == rhs.out_edges;
        }
        bool operator != (const LocalInfo& rhs) const {
          return !(*this == rhs);
        }

        //from_graph should point to the HashGraph LocalInfo is in, so LocalInfo
        //  methods (see <<)
        HashGraph<T>* from_graph;
        ics::HashSet<std::string>                        out_nodes;
        ics::HashSet<std::string>                        in_nodes;
        ics::HashSet<ics::pair<std::string,std::string>> out_edges;
        ics::HashSet<ics::pair<std::string,std::string>> in_edges;
   };//LocalInfo
```

In my assignment operator, I'm supposed to copy the `rhs` graph into `this` and return the newly copied graph. My professor says I have to use `connect` which is in the `LocalInfo` class, so that each copied `LocalInfo` object will reset `from_graph` to the new graph (`this`).

Here is what my function looks like right now:

```
template<class T>
HashGraph<T>& HashGraph<T>::operator = (const HashGraph<T>& rhs){
    this->clear();
    for(auto i : rhs.node_values) {
        HashGraph<T>::LocalInfo temp;
        temp.connect(rhs);
        node_values[i.first] = temp; 
    }
    edge_values = rhs.edge_values;
    return *this;
}
```

This however does not compile because of the line `temp.connect(rhs)`, where it says there is `no matching function call to HashGraph<int>::LocalInfo::connect(const HashGraph<int>&)`.

The way my professor has it set up is that `this->clear()` does empty the `this` HashGraph. To copy the `node_values` map over, I use his iterator to iterate through the `rhs.node_values` map.

As a note, he has it set up so that calling `node_values[i.first] = temp` will actually create a key in `node_values` which is the key from the right hand side, and will then assign the value `temp` (which is a `LocalInfo` object) into that key.

But like I said, this doesn't compile. So how can I use `connect()` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to connect to `rhs` and not to `this`? rhs is `const HashGraph<int> &` which make you don't have an access to modify to the structure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need to have rhs inside of connect. Then store that in the lhs. Since the graph passed into connect (g) gets assigned to `from_graph` which applies to `this`

Answer (score 2):

The function wants a pointer, not an object or reference.

```
temp.connect(&rhs);
```

Comment: It's giving me this error: `error: invalid conversion from 'const ics::HashGraph<int>*' to 'ics::HashGraph<int>*' [-fpermissive]
   temp.connect(&rhs);
   ^
../src/hash_graph.hpp:71:14: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void ics::HashGraph<T>::LocalInfo::connect(ics::HashGraph<T>*) [with T = int]' [-fpermissive]
         void connect(HashGraph<T>* g) {from_graph = g;}`

Comment: @Alex: Oh yes, I didn't notice it was the `const` function argument. You'll have to make it not `const` if you need something to store a non-`const` pointer to it. Or maybe you want to connect `this` not `*rhs`. It's hard to guess what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Ah.. yeah `temp.connect(this);` worked. I have no idea why to be honest since I thought I was supposed to connect the right hand side to the left hand side.